# Achieving lookup(user) custom fields of account in email recipient

Tags: apex

How to access lookup to user custom field of Account standard object in email recipient

Comment: are you sending email using 1. standard button 2. APex 3. Workflow?

Comment: I am sending email using Workflow rule.

Answer (score 1):

you can select "Related User" option while creating a new email alert in Workflow. You will be able to see there custom user field "lookup" that you created. Just add it in **"Selected Recipients"** from **"Available Recipients"**

[image]

Comment: But in related user it is only showing Related User: Last Modified By option

Comment: The above screenshot is for contact object.. But it should work on Account too... I ll give it a shot and let u know..

Comment: I have checked in custom object I have created naming Invoice but it is displaying only Related User: Last Modified By

Comment: Do you want this on Account or Custom Object?